# ApiGen Template config config.neon doesn't exist - Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans, pear, apigen

I've recently upgraded Ubuntu, and the localhost root which was `/var/www` was changed to `/var/www/html`.

I made all necessary adjustments, but now apigen seems locked into searching for the `config.neon` file at the old www location.

This is the error:

```
Template config "/var/www/ApiGen/templates/default/config.neon" doesn't exist
```

I had to change the `/usr/bin/apigen` to fix a previous include error, but I cannot seem to find the file where the location of the config.neon file. It had even occurred to me that perhaps pear installer had initial control over this, but I cannot find any clues on this either.

So the simple question, how do I fix the above `doesn't exist` error?

Answer (score 0):

I simply fixed this by using Ubuntu's software center to install it, as an alternative to pear. Now it works wonderfully.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if you found the solution yourself!